# Kubernetes poniting to oracle DB in separate VM

Tags: oracle, kubernetes

I am currently working ona kubernetes deployment,My application is running in Kubernetes cluster while my DB is running in a different VM.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: dcalln
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: dcalln
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: dcalln
    spec:
     containers:
     - name: dcalln
       image: "xxx.io/registry:1.0.88-ad3c142-2108190744"
       ports:
       - containerPort: 8080
     imagePullSecrets:
       - name: regcred
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: dcalln
  name: dcalln
  namespace: testnamespace
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 1512
  externalIPs:
  - XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX is my oracle DB server. Its not part of kubernetes cluster.But I see the DB connection is not happening. Is there anything I am missing. How do I change my deployment specification to correctly point to DB

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud providor? How did you check the connection between cluster and DB?

Comment: Kubernetes 1.20.8.Cluster is setup using Rancher in VMs. ping to the DB server is working from application pod. DB server is not part of cluster. Its in a different VM

Comment: How did you check the connection between cluster and DB? You wrote: "But I see the DB connection is not happening."